# Laptop Mouse Pad Allows for Pinch - What is the Associated Event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events, pinch

My laptop has a mousepad that allows for pinching.

I am writing a html/javascript page where I want to write my own scaling function for pinch.

This is a website page for mobiles and desktops. (I am testing the desktop.)

What event should I be capturing? At the moment I have:

```
window.addEventListener("touchstart", mycanvasOnTouchStart, false);
window.addEventListener("touchmove", mycanvasOnTouchMove, false);
window.addEventListener("touchend", mycanvasOnTouchEnd, false);
```

None of my functions fire.

Also, the default action of the pinch, namely zooming the whole html page, continues, even though I have put the following in the HEAD element of the page:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: A touchpad likely does not fire a touch event. The mouse driver will emulate some other event, probably the scroll wheel or a keyboard shortcut, which will likely be impossible to distinguish via the Javascript API.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot seem to trigger the event it does do. I have tried document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", mycanvasOnMouseWheel, false); and document.body.addEventListener("onwheel", mycanvasOnMouseWheel, false);, but nothing. Am I doing something wrong. Or how do I even turn it off?

Comment: You might be looking for the `wheel` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel

Comment: I can catch the wheel event from a mouse in my code, but when I pinch on the mouse pad, the wheel event does not fire.